# How to access local paths on TYPO3 using eID

Tags: ajax, typo3, fluid, extbase

I have an image map on my frontend and from there I need to access some images that are stored on different folders under the fileadmin directory. And I'm trying to do it with eID, following this example:
[http://www.alexanderschnitzler.de/2011/06/howto-ajax-requests-with-extbase-and-fluid/][1]

But my problem is that I can only access one directory. I haven't been able to access different directories based on the user selection from my front end.

This is the code of what I been trying to do:
**On my Controller** I have an ajaxAction, where I need to give the full path of one directory, because I haven't figure it out how pass the directory id on to my ajaxAction, here might be my question and maybe the solution:

```
/**
 * @return void
 */
public function ajaxAction() {

    $image_file_path = "fileadmin/Images/Sattic/Amik/small";
    //$image_file_path = "fileadmin/Images/Sattic/'+$id+'";
    $d = dir($image_file_path) or die("Wrong path: $image_file_path");
    while (false !== ($entry = $d ->read())) {
        if($entry != '.' && $entry != '..' && !is_dir($dir.$entry)) 
        $images[] = $entry;
    }
    $d->close();

    rsort($images);
    return json_encode($images);
}
```

On my index.html I have a map tag where the function updateImage(id) is called, when the user clicks on the different areas and my updataImage(id) function looks like this:

```
function updateImageGallery(id) {
console.log(id);

var ajaxUrl = "{f:uri.action(action:'ajax', pageType:'100101')}";

$.getJSON(ajaxUrl, function(data) {
    var items1 = [];
    var items2 = [];
    $data = data;
    console.log('dataLength: ' + $data.length);
    console.log('dataArray: ' + $data);

    $.each($data.slice(0, 4), function(key, val) {
        valLink = val.replace("small.", "");
        items1.push('<td><a href="fileadmin/Images/Sattic/' + id +'/'+ valLink +'" target="_blank"><img width="145" height="145" id="" src="fileadmin/Images/Sattic/' + id +'/small/'+ val +'"/></a></td>');
    });
    $('<tr/>', {
        html: items1.join('')
    }).appendTo('#glRegion');

    $.each($data.slice(4, 8), function(key, val) {
        valLink = val.replace("small.", "");
        items2.push('<td><a href="fileadmin/Images/Sattic/' + id +'/'+ valLink +'" target="_blank"><img width="145" height="145" id="" src="fileadmin/Images/Sattic/' + id +'/small/'+ val +'"/></a></td>');
    });
    $('<tr/>', {
        html: items2.join('')
    }).appendTo('#glRegion');

});
return false;
```

}

I would like to be able to pass from updateImageGallery(id) function, the id of the directory, so I could get the images for each directory.

Is it possible to do this? I hope so, I have 30 different regions and if I solve my problem the way I'm doing now I would need to use 30 different eID's. I guess it might be a smarter way to solve this.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `t3lib_div::_GET('myid')` to access the `myid` get variable.

I guess you can use `var ajaxUrl = "{f:uri.action(action:'ajax',**myid:id,** pageType:'100101')}";` to set it.

Anyway, sure to generate a list of valid paths/ids inside you PHP script and check the get parameter agains those.